# glutBitmapString() was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, opengl, compilation, glut

when i try to plot some strings with the following code:

```
    // label min and max for current vector
    glRasterPos2f(nx+1,y1);
    glutBitmapString(GLUT_BITMAP_8_BY_13,"min");

    glRasterPos2f(nx+1,y2);
    glutBitmapString(GLUT_BITMAP_8_BY_13,"max");
```

i get the error

```
error: ‘glutBitmapString’ was not declared in this scope
```

upon compilation. the crazy thing is that

```
    // label min and max for current vector
    glRasterPos2f(nx+1,y1);
    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_8_BY_13,'1');

    glRasterPos2f(nx+1,y2);
    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_8_BY_13,'2');
```

compiles just fine, so it's not like i have not included the glut library or anything (i have glutSwapBuffers() and a bajillion other glut calls as well!)

why on earth won't glutBitmapString() compile? i have checked the spelling and everything, and it just won't compile!

Comment: Does the code compile if you write `glutBitmapString(GLUT_BITMAP_8_BY_13, (const unsigned char *) "min");`? Your `char` type might be signed by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What implementation of Glut are you using?  According to the FreeGlut documentation, the original Glut does not include `glutBitmapString`

http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/docs/api.php#FontRendering

And indeed, there is no mention of `glutBitmapString` in the Glut documentation
http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node75.html#SECTION000110000000000000000

If you really need to use this function it looks like you will need to use FreeGlut.

Answer (score 4):

just add one line:

```
#include < GL/freeglut.h>
```

This function is a new function added by freeglut which is not exited in glut